# AWS amplify adding files in public directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify to upload video in s3 bucket when i am giving key in amplify options its creating a public folder and then taking that key.

```
Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
            "user/hello/123321.mp4",
            exampleFile,
            result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey()),
            storageFailure -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Upload failed", storageFailure)
    );
```

> s3 bucket its going inside - public/user/hello/123321.mp4

I just want my files to go in key and not create any public folder.

is there any option to do that ?

Comment: Facing the same issue while using amplify in Flutter, in Javascript I found an answer here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/332#issuecomment-602606514, but not for Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Storage.put(
"file name", 
file (actual file from input) ,
{
level: "public", 
customPrefix: {public: "folder name in S3 /"},
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I wonder why it isn't covered in the amplify docs here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Levels have been explained in the official documentation below.

https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/storage/upload/

Example usage from there:

```
uploadData({
        key: file.name,
        data: file,
        options: {
          accessLevel: 'private'
        }
      });
```